# How to format number input in angular

Tags: angular, input, formatting, numbers, currency

I have a number input like this 
[image]

and i want something like this (no matters what the sepparator will be)

[image]

My actual code works as follows:

```
<div class="row center-xs" *ngFor="let item of listItem;let i=index">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input [disabled]="item.lock!=0" type="number" matInput [placeholder]="item.name" [(ngModel)]="item.concept" >                                      
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive code has some bugs that I fixed.

I also fixed the problem with converting from string to number. The variable linked to the input was assigned a string value instead of a number and this caused errors when sending data to the APIs.

The ngModule would no longer be used, it could be used but it would be superfluous.

its use would remain in this way.

> <input type="text" matInput [(localizedNumericInput)]="invoice.value">

```
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, forwardRef, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/material/input';


@Directive({
  selector: 'input[localizedNumericInput]',
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: LocalizedNumericInputDirective },
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => LocalizedNumericInputDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class LocalizedNumericInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  locale = 'en';
  decimalMarker: string;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {
  }

  private _value: string | null;

  get value(): string | null {
    return this._value;
  }

  @Input('value')
  set value(value: string | null) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(value);
  }

  @Input('localizedNumericInput') set valor(valor:number) {
    if (!valor) {valor = 0;}

    this.formatValue(valor.toString());
  }
  @Output('localizedNumericInputChange') valorChange = new EventEmitter<number>();


  @Input('objeto') objeto: any;
  @Input('propiedad') propiedad: string;

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  input(value) {
    //Find all numerics, decimal marker(, or .) and -
    //It will delete thousandSeparator cos it's always opposite to decimal marker
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    //Separate value on before and after decimal marker
    let [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    if (!integer) { integer = 0; }
    if (!decimal) { decimal = 0; }

    //Send non localized value, with dot as decimalMarker to API
    this._value = decimal ? integer.concat('.', decimal) : integer;

    // If decimal separator is last character don't update
    // because it will delete . || ,
    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      this._value = value;
    }

    // here to notify Angular Validators
    this._onChange(this._value);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  _onBlur() {
    /**
     * Adding thousand separators
     */
    this.formatValue(this._value);

    this.valorChange.emit(parseFloat(this._value));
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    this.unFormatValue();
  }

  _onChange(value: any): void { }

  /**
   * @param value
   * apply formatting on value assignment
   */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(this._value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() { }

  isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value: any) {
    return isNaN(value[value.length - 1]);
  }


  private formatValue(value: string | null) {
    if (value === null) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
      return;
    }

    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value.toString())) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = value;
      return;
    }

    // Conclude the decimal and thousand separators from locale
    const [thousandSeparator, decimalMarker] = formatNumber(1000.99, this.locale).replace(/\d/g, '');
    this.decimalMarker = decimalMarker;

    //Here value should always come with . as decimal marker thus any other behavior is bug
    let [integer, decimal] = value.toString().split('.');

    if (!integer) { integer = '0'; }
    if (!decimal) { decimal = '00'; }

    //Group every three elements, and add thousandSeparator after them
    this.element.nativeElement.value = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);

    //Add decimals and decimalMarker if any
    if (decimal) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this.element.nativeElement.value.concat(decimalMarker, decimal);
    }
  }

  private unFormatValue() {
    const value = this.element.nativeElement.value;

    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      return;
    }

    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    let [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    if (!integer) { integer = '0'; }
    if (!decimal) { decimal = '00'; }

    this._value = integer.concat('.', decimal);
    if (value) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this._value;
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for share this. May be helpful for someone

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. To solve it I have used this [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-material-matinput-control-with-thousands-separation-ebcbb7b027f4). I have created a slightly modified version to fit my needs.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/material';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[localizedNumericInput]',
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: LocalizedNumericInputDirective },
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => LocalizedNumericInputDirective),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class LocalizedNumericInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
  locale = 'en';
  decimalMarker: string;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) {
  }

  private _value: string | null;

  get value(): string | null {
    return this._value;
  }

  @Input('value')
  set value(value: string | null) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(value);
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  input(value) {
    //Find all numerics, decimal marker(, or .) and -
    //It will delete thousandSeparator cos it's always opposite to decimal marker
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    //Separate value on before and after decimal marker
    const [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    //Send non localized value, with dot as decimalMarker to API
    this._value = decimal ? integer.concat('.', decimal) : integer;

    // If decimal separator is last character don't update
    // because it will delete . || ,
    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      this._value = value;
    }

    // here to notify Angular Validators
    this._onChange(this._value);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  _onBlur() {
    /**
     * Adding thousand separators
     */
    this.formatValue(this._value);
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  onFocus() {
    this.unFormatValue();
  }

  _onChange(value: any): void {}

  /**
   * @param value
   * apply formatting on value assignment
   */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
    this.formatValue(this._value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: any) => void) {
    this._onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value: any) {
    return isNaN(value[value.length - 1]);
  }


  private formatValue(value: string | null) {
    if (value === null) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
      return;
    }

    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = value;
      return;
    }

    // Conclude the decimal and thousand separators from locale
    const [thousandSeparator, decimalMarker] = formatNumber(1000.99, this.locale).replace(/\d/g, '');
    this.decimalMarker = decimalMarker;

    //Here value should always come with . as decimal marker thus any other behavior is bug
    const [integer, decimal] = value.split('.');

    //Group every three elements, and add thousandSeparator after them
    this.element.nativeElement.value = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, thousandSeparator);

    //Add decimals and decimalMarker if any
    if (decimal) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this.element.nativeElement.value.concat(decimalMarker, decimal);
    }
  }

  private unFormatValue() {
    const value = this.element.nativeElement.value;
    if (this.isLastCharacterDecimalSeparator(value)) {
      return;
    }
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[^\\d${this.decimalMarker}-]`, 'g');
    const [integer, decimal] = value.replace(regExp, '').split(this.decimalMarker);

    this._value = integer.concat('.', decimal);
    if (value) {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = this._value;
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.value = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, i had forgotten about this question for some time and i finally solved it by separating the formatting functions and the angular's binding itself. But this approach by directives is by far so much more accurate. I will mark this as accepted. Thanks for provide this solution, i think it will be useful for someone

Comment: @alexander-poshtaruk is the real hero here :)

Answer (score -3):

You can make use of the 'number' pipe of Angular.

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

This pipe controls the fraction digits as well as how a number will be formatted based on a locale (default: en-US).

So a number like: `2000000` will be transformed to `2,000,000`. Depending on the locale the separators will be differ.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'number-pipe',
  template: `
    <!--output '2,000,000'-->
    {{e | number}}
  `
})
export class NumberPipeComponent {
  e: number = 2000000;
}
```

Comment: In this case i can't use the pipe, because i'm not using numbers on the way you talk and i'm using two way binding on the input, not only posting the value

Comment: You can't use pipes in input controls.