# Number pipe taking only three digits before decimal

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular app. I have a input field. My code is as follows

```
<input matInput style="width:100%;" type="number" [ngModel]="input | number : '1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="input = $event"   autocomplete="off">
```

stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-slider-simple-slider-example-pl2peu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In this  input field I am using number pipe. The problem I am facing with number pipe is if I enter a number in input field,then it is taking only 3 digits before decimal, if I try to enter 4th digit before decimal number disappers. I want to allow user to enter as many number as he wish before decimal. How can I resolve this?

Comment: this is not how you can have thousand separators or decimals in input, see this : [https://stackoverflow.com/q/50147818/5747727](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50147818/5747727)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to implement ControlValueAccessor and create your own custom form control that formats the data the way that you want. This is a similar question and the accepted answer has a custom form control implementation that should put you on the right track,

[How to format number input in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52787570/how-to-format-number-input-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Other options futhermore the comments

You can make something like this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617629/how-to-display-specific-decimal-places-but-still-keep-raw-value-in-input-angular/68617829#68617829). If you has a variable in .ts focus

```
focus:boolean=false;
```

You can write some like

```
<input matInput style="width:100%;" type="number" 
   [ngModel]="focus?inputTarget:(inputTarget | number : '1.2-2')" 
   (ngModelChange)="inputTarget = $event"  
   (blur)="focus=false" 
   (focus)="focus=true"  autocomplete="off">
```

Or you can make a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[format]',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class FormatDirective implements OnInit {
  focus:boolean=false;
  value:any;
  @Input('format') formato:string
  @HostListener('blur') _(){
    this.focus=false;
    this.value=this.control.control.value;
    this.control.control.setValue(formatNumber(this.value,'en-US',this.formato))
  }
  @HostListener('focus') __(){
    this.focus=true;
    this.control.control.setValue(this.value)
  }
  constructor(private control:NgControl){}
  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.value=this.control.control.value;
      this.control.control.setValue(formatNumber(this.value,'en-US',this.formato))
    })
  }
}
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-slider-simple-slider-example-5h8s3p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformat.directive.ts)

NOTE: If you "format" the number with thousand separators the type can not be "number"

Comment: It is working fine for values before decimal. But once be click on input field it shows all the values after decimal. Is there is any way in your solution you can restrict it to always two values after decimal whether we click it or not

Comment: I add a new answer mixing this answer and another one about mask.

Answer (score 0):

if we want that not allow more than 2 decimals, we need mix the before answer and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816)

The directive can be like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[decimal]'
})
export class DecimalDirective implements OnInit {
  
  @Input('decimal') set _(value){
    this.formato=value;
    const digits=value.split('-')[1]
    this.regExpr=new RegExp("^[+-]?([1-9]\\d*|0)?(\\.\\d\{0,"+digits+"\})?$");
  }
  
  private formato:string=null
  private _oldvalue: string = "";
  private regExpr: any;
  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  private control:AbstractControl;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,private ngcontrol:NgControl,@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private language) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.control=ngcontrol.control
  }
  @HostBinding('style.text-align') get="right"
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  change($event) {

    let item = $event.target
    let value = item.value;
    let pos = item.selectionStart;
    let matchvalue = value;
    let noMatch: boolean = (value && !(this.regExpr.test(matchvalue)));
    if (noMatch) {
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
      if (item.value.length < this._oldvalue.length && pos == 0)
        pos = 2;
      this.el.value=this._oldvalue;

      item.value = this._oldvalue;
      this.control.setValue(item.value)
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      this._oldvalue = value;
    }
  }
  @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
  onFocus() {
    if (this.formato)
    this.el.value = this._oldvalue;
  }

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value: any) {
    if (this.formato)
    this.transform(value);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.transform(this.control.value);
  
    })
  }
  
  transform(value: any) {
    this._oldvalue = value;
    if (value && !isNaN(value)) {
      this.el.value=formatNumber(+this._oldvalue, this.language, this.formato);
      const formated=this.el.value.split(',').join('')
      if (formated.indexOf(this._oldvalue) >= 0) this._oldvalue = formated;
    }
  }
}
```

And you use as

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value" decimal="1.2-2">
```

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q8bkcr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdecimal.directive.ts)

Comment: this works fine. But is it possible that instead of making a separate directive, we can handle same thing in hmtl code <input matInput style="width:100%;" type="number" 
   [ngModel]="focus?inputTarget:(inputTarget | number : '1.2-2')" 
   (ngModelChange)="inputTarget = $event"  
   (blur)="focus=false" 
   (focus)="focus=true"  autocomplete="off">

Comment: @Julie, he "key" is in (blur) not only make "focus=false" else call a function to change the inputTarget in the way has only two decimals:`format()  { this.inputTarget=Math.round(+this.inputTarget*100)/100  }` and use `(blur)="focus=false;format()"`